How to prove if a list `n::l` is an in-order merge of 2 lists `n::l1` `l2`, then `l` is an in-order merge of `l1` and `l2` in Coq?
In IndProp.v of
Logical Foundations,
an exercise is to definde an inductive relation that a list is an in-order merge of
the other 2 lists. I tried to define it as:
Inductive merge {X:Type} : list X -> list X -> list X -> Prop :=
  | merge0 : merge [] [] []
  | merge1 n l1 l2 l (H: merge l1 l2 l) : merge (n::l1) l2 (n::l)
  | merge2 n l1 l2 l (H: merge l1 l2 l) : merge l1 (n::l2) (n::l).

The basic idea is that any l can be kept an in-order merge,
when it is grown by adding heads one by one from
elements that form l1 and l2.
Based on the same idea, it should be able to be reduced by taking away
the heads from l and l1 at the same time if they are in common.
So, I wrote down the proposition
Proposition merge_l_reduce: forall (X: Type) (n: X) l1 l2 l,
  merge (n::l1) l2 (n::l) -> merge l1 l2 l.

Is the proposition provable? If so, how to prove it?
I tried to prove it by
Proof.
intros X n l1 l2 l H.
inversion H as [
  | m l1' l2' l' Q Q1 Q2 Q3
  | m l1' l2' l' Q Q1 Q2 Q3].
(* For merge0, this branch will not come. *)
- (* for merge1 *)
  apply Q.
- (* for merge2 ... stuck here *) Abort.

The first 2 branches are easy, but I am stuck on the 3rd branch. Coq insists
the need to prove merge l1 (n::l2') l by merge (n::l1) l2' l where l2 = n::l2'.

For a concrete case, do you see how to derive merge [3] [3 ; 4] [3; 4; 3] ?

I see. Thanks for giving this counter-example.
